# Notify Google of new incoming links?

Tags: google-search-console

If I obtain a new incoming link to my website, can I inform Google of it using the Add URL tool?

Comment: Sorry but could you edit your question to make it comprehensible?

Comment: You cannot "notify Google of new incoming links" to your website!? Google finds these by itself - it is what it does. "Google Suggest a URL..." - you should already have submitted a sitemap and submitted URLs as part of getting indexed - this has nothing to do with incoming links.

Comment: What if you have a page on your website you wish Google to add to it's index?  Do you use the Suggest a URL tool for this?  If so, why does the page have to be on your website?

Comment: It doesn't matter if you submit a newly built page on your site to Google either by sitemap or by it's suggest a URL feature. That does not guarantee Google will crawl, let a lone index the page. HTML sitemaps are better, Google has mentioned this since they'll see the `a` tag links and crawl them for sure over deciding on how important your sitemap is vs the millions of others they need to crawl.

Comment: @Steve also you aren't clear in your question do you mean if another website other than your own links to you can you inform Google of this incoming link? If so you better wait. Don't you think it'll look a bit odd if you start submitting URL's for Google to crawl which don't belong to you but contain links to you?

Comment: Google bots crawl the web and find incoming links to your site by themselves. Just wait a little to see incoming links on webmaster tools.

Answer (score 2):

Google will find these links by itself. If not, the only way you can help it, to place a link to that url on a crawled page of your own. But that is useless, because if Google  does not find it by itself, it holds no strength, so does not help you to rank better.